# JavaScript Redirect to Django view with parameters

Tags: javascript, django, url, redirect, view

These lines of code produce an error, my question is, how can I pass the IDS and MESSAGES parameters to windows.location.href in Django view.

```
$(function () {
    console.log("HOME");
    let ids = 1;
    let messages = "My personal Message";
        
    let myurl = "{% url 'message-page' ids messages %}";  //ERROR HERE: IDS and MESSAGES are variables                    

    return window.location.href = myurl
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick that might work under most circumstances:

```
var url_mask = "{% url 'someview' ids messages %}".replace(/ids/, ids.toString()).replace(/messages/, messages.toString());
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried the trick and it gives me this error: Reverse for 'message-page' with arguments '('', <FallbackStorage: request=<WSGIRequest: GET '/test-page'>>)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['message\\-page/(?P<ids>[0-9]+)/(?P<messages>[^/]+)\\Z']